# Writing a custom plugin for Zepto with jQuery fallback

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

I am looking into [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/) with a jQuery fallback (as seen on Zepto's website) to see if it is viable for an upcoming project.

I was hoping to build a custom plugin using $.extend, but noticed in Zepto's example that they pass in Zepto as the `$` variable as does jQuery. Would there be a way to pass in whatever library is loaded?

**Zepto plugin:**

```
;(function($){
  $.extend($.fn, {
    foo: function(){ 
    }
  })
})(Zepto)
```

**jQuery plugin:**

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
  };
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: Updated answer.

My original thoughts were to simply pass `$` as the parameter, which works, but doesn't offer great portability if the plugin is to be distributed throughout various projects.

Instead you should use the `OR` operator to detect whether `Zepto` is loaded, falling back to `jQuery` if it isn't.

```
;(function($){
    $.extend($.fn, {
        foo: function(){ 
        }
    })
})(window.Zepto || window.jQuery)
```

Comment: Yes, the Zepto code itself writes only the needed one in. Could you explain what you mean by only passing the `$` as the parameter? Are you saying that I don't need `(Zepto);` or `(jQuery)` at the end of the plugin?

Comment: @PaulSham I've updated my answer with a much neater solution.

Comment: so where is the plugin name?

Comment: @vsync The plugin in my example would be called `foo`.

Comment: Why using `$.extend` this way? it's the same as just writing `$.fn.myPlugin =...` but your style is using a lot more lines of code..

Comment: @vsync It's a matter of preference. Either are perfectly acceptable and widely used. The original question pertains to passing the appropriate `Zepto` or `jQuery` object to the plugin, not the actual plugin code itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery.noConflict()` to avoid collision with another library that uses `$` alias. That way `$` would always be Zepto and you can use any other alias you want for jQuery, or just use the `jQuery` object itself

You can still use `$` in your jQuery code wrapped in `document.ready` if you pass it as an argument of `document.ready`;

API Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/